# Custom XML attributes without custom View in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-xml, android-custom-attributes

I'm trying to add custom XML attributes in existing View

Adding them to a custom View is not a big deal but I don't know how to access those attributes in a "basic" View (e.g. TextView, LinearLayout, ImageView ...)

And this is more difficult when there are Fragment and / or Library project involved

So far here is my code

Customs attributes definitions and XML (attrs.xml and the layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="StarWars">
    <attr name="jedi" format="string" />
    <attr name="rank" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:sw="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    sw:jedi="Obiwan" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rank"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    sw:rank="Master" />
```

Since I inflate this on an Fragment (so no onCreate with attrs arg !), the only way to try to get the 2 sw custom attributes is to :

1. Set a custom LayoutInflater.Factory to the Fragment LayoutInflater in onCreateView

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

     LayoutInflater layoutInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(inflater.getContext());
     layoutInflater.setFactory(new StarWarsLayoutFactory());

     View fragmentView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.jedi, container, false);
     ((TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(android.R.id.jedi)).setText("Yep");

     return fragmentView;
   }
   ```
2. Trying to get the custom attributes on the custom LayoutInflater.Factory :

   ```
   public class StarWarsLayoutFactory implements Factory {
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                 *** What to do here ? ***

         return null;
     }
   }
   ```

Anyone have had this kind of question ?

What I'm missing here ?

Thx in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally done this :)

You have to create a new `LayoutInflater.Factory` as I did on the OP but since the Factory is used for all the inflated layout View, and you have to return null on your `Factory.onCreateView` (to let Android handle the inflation) you must cache your custom XML attibutes somewhere

So here the solution :

- Your layout XML View must have and android:id
- Create the class which will keep your custom attributes :

```java
    public class AttributeParser {

    private AttributeParserFactory mFactory;
    private Map<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> mAttributeList;

    private class AttributeParserFactory implements LayoutInflater.Factory{
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            String id = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "id");

            if(id != null){
                // String with the reference character "@", so we strip it to keep only the reference
                id = id.replace("@", "");

                TypedArray libraryStyledAttributeList = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.NewsHubLibrary);
                HashMap<Integer, String> libraryViewAttribute = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                int i = 0;

                for(int attribute : R.styleable.NewsHubLibrary){
                    String attributeValue = libraryStyledAttributeList.getString(i);

                    if(attributeValue != null)
                        libraryViewAttribute.put(attribute, attributeValue);

                    i++;
                }

                if(!libraryViewAttribute.isEmpty())
                    mAttributeList.put(Integer.valueOf(id), libraryViewAttribute);

                libraryStyledAttributeList.recycle();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    public AttributeParser(){
        mAttributeList = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>>();
        mFactory = new AttributeParserFactory();
    }

    public void clear() {
        mAttributeList.clear();
    }

    public LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        clear();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(inflater.getContext());
        layoutInflater.setFactory(mFactory);

        return layoutInflater;
    }

    public void setFactory(LayoutInflater inflater){
        inflater.cloneInContext(inflater.getContext()).setFactory(mFactory);
    }

    public void setViewAttribute(Activity activity) {
        for(Entry<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> attribute : mAttributeList.entrySet())
            if(activity.findViewById((Integer) attribute.getKey()) != null)
                activity.findViewById((Integer) attribute.getKey()).setTag(attribute.getValue());

    }

    public void setViewAttribute(View view) {
        for(Entry<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> attribute : mAttributeList.entrySet())
            if(view.findViewById((Integer) attribute.getKey()) != null)
                view.findViewById((Integer) attribute.getKey()).setTag(attribute.getValue());
    }

    public Map<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> getAttributeList() {
        return mAttributeList;
    }

    public void setAttributeList(Map<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> attributeList) {
        this.mAttributeList = attributeList;
    }
    }
```

- Your custom attributes will be stored in each View tag when you use the AttributeParser :

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = mAttributeParser.getLayoutInflater(inflater);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.jedi, null);
    mAttributeParser.setViewAttribute(view);
```

Comment: Can you also share your attrs.xml?

Comment: it works fine with support-v4:22.0.0, but with higher versions (for example support-v4:23.0.1) onCreateView is not called and mAttributeList size is 0. Why?

Comment: I really don't know, this workaround was long time ago. Check if Google changed the way LayoutInflater works

Comment: It probably needs to be a Factory2

Answer (score 0):

Standard `TextView` and such will not access these attributes. You may extend it though and provide functionality that includes reading those custom attributes.

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.StarWars, 0, 0);

String jedi = a.getText(R.styleable.StarWars_jedi);
String rank = a.getText(R.styleable.StarWars_rank);

a.recycle();
```

Remember to always call `recycle()` at the end.

Comment: Yeah I know how to do that with extended View but I need to achieve this one for all Views, extended or not