# How do I implement LayoutInflater.Factory?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I'm implementing a library that will make use of MVVM design pattern easier in Android. For binding I need to read custom attributes on existing views. It is possible with `LayoutInflater.Factory` ([Custom XML attributes without custom View in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800642/custom-xml-attributes-without-custom-view-in-fragment))

But as you can see in `onCreateView (String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` header there is no `View` in arguments and I need it in my case... How do I get it? Should I create it myself?

How do I do it so I get equivalent of "default behavior" (as in "[Return null for the default behavior](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.Factory.html)")?

Answer (score 0):

Get the activity from the onAttach and get the View on that activity

**example:**

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

**get the View from activity:**

```
this.activity.getWindow().getDecorView()
```